# Authentication using Server Variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

There is an asp.net website in which authentication is as follows. The link to the website will be access from a portal. Using cleartrust, the server variables will be set. One of such server variable is “UserID”.

In the homepage, following logic is used. It retrieves the server variable “UserID”. If it is returning a non-null value, it is considered as authenticated.

I need to prove that the above approach is not enough. That means, when somebody else make a request to the website url by setting the server variable, they can see data. I want to create another website which will call the current website by setting the server variable. Is it possible to do so?

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string user = getCtHeader(this.Request, "UserID").Trim();

    }

    public static string getCtHeader(HttpRequest request, string key)
    {
        string value = request.ServerVariables[key];
        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can try to use WebRequest to load the authentication page from another site, calling the GetResponse() method

Comment: Are you basically trying to demonstrate that this system is vulnerable to Session fixation ?

Answer (score 0):

write smth like [C# WebClient login to accounts.google.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8601302/c-sharp-webclient-login-to-accounts-google-com), just change your headers, receive data from server and that's all