# WebClient: Logging into Gmail

Tags: c#, gmail, webclient

I've been trying to log into Gmail using:

```
WebClient Web = new WebClient();
Web.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Email, Password, "https://mail.google.com");
```

and then browse the email using `IHTMLDocument2` interface by getting the id associated to each email, building up the url, navigating to that url and using `DownloadString` method, pass the HTML content to the `IHTMLDocument2` interface.

The problem is that google does not accept the credentials that I send so I can never log in. However, after a few attempts I saw that this activity has been monitored by Google as I saw a notification about that on the actual email account.

I would like to know how this problem can be solved or is it possible at all to log into Gmail using `WebClient`? if yes, how exactly ?

Comment: This might help you out..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8601302/c-sharp-webclient-login-to-accounts-google-com

Comment: Of course it is possible, as a browser also just sends HTTP requests, but you should not want to do this. Web applications have APIs for this, such as the [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/). The front-end of Gmail is secured against automation like you're trying to do. If you want to beat this, you'll have to reverse engineer it using a real browser and a tool like Fiddler, and it may prove to be relatively hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Fiddler to observe what the browser does. Fiddler can capture HTTPS traffic. A Google login is more complex than you might think.

The `Credentials` property has no effect on web forms. There is no standardized way to have a login form in HTML. `WebClient` cannot possibly know how the Google login form works. It cannot possibly automate this for you.