# Bypass login and Download Zip file from URL

Tags: c#, webclient

I want to download a zip file form URL.It contains 20 to 30 CSV file and has total size between 50 KB to 100 KB. I have tried using below code but it is not working. 
When i directly open URL from web browser it redirects to login page and after successful login download the zip file.

```
  using (var client = new WebClient())
  {
    client.DownloadFile("http://MyURL","Myfile.zip");
  }
```

If i provide Download URL of CSV file in above code then it download html login page. Also tried by providing credential and header information as below but it is not working.

```
    using (var client = new WebClient())
      {
         client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
         client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip");
         client.DownloadFile("http://MyURL","Myfile.zip");
      }
```

I am using C# windows application.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8601302/c-sharp-webclient-login-to-accounts-google-com  it may help you to login and after login you can download ur zip files.

Comment: Tried a lot using webResponse,WebRequest,setting different headers,using WebClient but not succeed.Does it possible that while publishing user have put restriction on downloading of file?

Comment: Yes its possible but you can download file using filling username/password to form via your window application and trigger click to like after that ..